# How to handle selection when using GMSAutocompleteFetcher in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, google-places-api

I have google place autocomplete which display an GMSAutocompleteFetcher. the code is come from [Google developer website](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#call_gmsplacesclient) but the problem is I can't find a way how to handle selection right after user seeing the words appear on the textView to display it as place ID, so far this is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps

    class FetcherSampleViewController: UIViewController {

      var textField: UITextField?
      var resultText: UITextView?
      var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handletap:")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None

        // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
        let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366,
          longitude: 151.134002)
        let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725,
          longitude: 151.200349)
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
          coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

        // Set up the autocomplete filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .Establishment

        // Create the fetcher.
        fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
        fetcher?.delegate = self

        textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 0,
          width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 5.0, height: 44.0))
        textField?.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
        textField?.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:",
          forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

        resultText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45.0,
          width: self.view.bounds.size.width,
          height: self.view.bounds.size.height - 45.0))
        resultText?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        resultText?.text = "No Results"
        resultText?.editable = false
        resultText?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.view.addSubview(textField!)
        self.view.addSubview(resultText!)
      }

      func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(textField.text!)
      }
      func handletap (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
      print("I dont know what to do here")

      }
    }

    extension FetcherSampleViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {
      func didAutocompleteWithPredictions(predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    let resultsStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for prediction in predictions {
        resultsStr.appendAttributedString(prediction.attributedPrimaryText)
        resultsStr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
    }
    resultText?.attributedText = resultsStr
}

      func didFailAutocompleteWithError(error: NSError) {
        resultText?.text = error.localizedDescription
      }
    }
```

I use UITapGestureRecognizer but I don't know what should I do. If you can help me I would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the predictions are just newline-delimited rows in a text field, it's going to be difficult to tell which of them the user tapped on.

How about instead of a UITextView, you use a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) and have one row per prediction. This will make it easy to detect which prediction was selected.